# How to make a function which will trigger download of specific file for specific key entered by user?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, download

I have made a text box and a button. Now can anyone please help me making a function of how I can do this?

I want the user to enter a specific alphanumeric key which will be given by the website end in some other way. It will be alphanumeric. The user will have to enter the key in the text box and then click on the button to download a specific file that only the alphanumeric key can access. Then if the key match with a particular file, it will get downloaded. There will be already available so many other files too but one with the matched key will get downloaded. Please help me...

My code :

```html
<center>
        <input class="keyBox" type="text" placeholder="Enter your download key">
        <br><br>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-style btn-primary">Download</button>
        </div>
        </button>
  </center>
```

Comment: are you using any API for downloading files from the server?

Comment: `<center>` has been deprecated for 22 years. Consider using CSS, e.g. `text-align: center;`.

Comment: No not from any API or any other link. It will be downloaded from the directory or folder I have kept the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact requirements, but this should work, assuming you have a server with an API endpoint that takes the key as a query parameter. (Adjust the generated URL according to your requirements.)

```html
<!-- Add this after the HTML in your question -->
<script>
    function onClick(event) {
        // You should change the button's type to "button".
        // Then you won't need this line.
        event.preventDefault()

        const inputElement = document.querySelector('input')
        const filename = inputElement.value

        location.href = `/path/to/${filename}`
    }

    const button = document.querySelector('button')

    button.addEventListener('click', onClick)
</script>
```

As long as the API endpoint returns the correct `Content-Disposition` headers, the browser should attempt to download the file instead of navigate to the URL.

You should probably use `id` attributes so that `document.querySelector` doesn't select the wrong elements. Then you can use `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: No not from any API or any other link. It will be downloaded from the directory or folder I have kept the file.

I will update the key daily no problem in that. Just create the function as I am a very beginner at JavaScript. It will just check the entered key, matched with? download the file which is linked or assign with the key

Comment: @MdMimAkhtar I adjusted the answer a bit. Instead of using a query parameter, it uses the value entered in the input as the name of the file. `/path/to/` is just an example, of course. Adjust it according to your requirements.

Comment: can you please explain a bit more. I am unable to understand. how to put the file location their suppose my file location is completedproject/imagefile/abcd.html. How do I put this there? I know this is really a kiddy question but I am learning

Comment: Assuming you don't need the user to type the `.html` extension: ``location.href = `completedproject/imagefile/${filename}.html`;``

Comment: OK, please specify *all* the information required to answer your question. It’s impossible to know what you want if you don’t specify it.

Comment: A text box where the user will enter a specific alphanumeric key which will be given by us to download the completed file. Now I will be keeping all the completed files in that folder but only a certain key will trigger a certain file to download. Suppose abcd.jpg; cdef.jpg; tghb.jpg all are there, then the user has to enter abcd.jpg and click the button to download abcd.jpg. Otherwise, something like this... will make a specific key for that like if input == specific key; download: thisfile.jpg; something like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236294/discussion-between-md-mim-akhtar-and-distortum).